# Viewing all of a C# class extensions and partials in one place

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ide

Extension have a pesky way of hiding away in multiple files, having been named nothing to do with the original class being extended.

For example: On a project I am working on I find a class called Transaction, but of course it has been extended, I tried looking at the class in the class view, but none of the extension method where showing!

Is there a way to view the complete class even if the class is partial or have extension methods in number of files? How does one bring together all the fragmented partial and extension parts for viewing only (and/or navigate to them)?

Comment: Do you mean Extension that is Inside the same NameSpace?

Comment: Extension methods might not even be in the same assembly. You could find all references to the class, but you'd miss some if they were in an unloaded project or applied to an interface or parent class.

Comment: @Aizen : not only them, I just want to see all the class with its extensions and partials displayed in one place. But if that is too much then how does one just sees the extensions for one name space?

Comment: I am also using VS 2013, but so far when I use another NameSpace. I can see every class that I import in the Class View. If I want to Filter all the Class from a namespace I just type the name space ending extension to my search bar. For example Linq. I put it in the search so it will filter all class by filter. Also I use, F12 to go to definition to go to the Class. I click on the Class name then press F12

Comment: @Aizen : how do you find that classes extensions?

Comment: Lol I just typed in "Extensions" in the Search Bar of the Class view.

Comment: @Aizen : yes, but I want to see extensions and partials of just one specific class at a time, that shows all the extensions :)

Comment: If you want to make your own Views. Why don't you try to Object Browser. Instead of the Class View?

Comment: @Aizen : Tried that already, it doesn't show the extension methods of the class, same as class view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the benefits of extension methods is to allow extensions on otherwise closed code. Therefore by their very nature they could be all over the place. You could find all references to the class in the solution and cross reference with what intellisense gives you? I like to place my extensions etc in clearly named folders and or namespaces.

Comment: Yes, but when working on other peoples projects, they decide to extend a class somewhere, and while I am focused on the class it would be nice to view it in all it's glory, with all the available extensions and partials for being displayed in one please, and being able to navigate back through between them.

Comment: Yes it would be nice. Is intellisense not giving you enough info?